# Okta SSO integration with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, okta

I am working on a POC to integrate the Okta SSO with Spring MVC with custom login and index jsp pages.I have configured the Okta account and configured Sign-in redirect URIs and Sign-out redirect URIs

I am referring : https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring/tree/master/custom-login

Sign-in redirect URIs : http://localhost:8080/authorization-code/callback. Below is my appication yaml file content

```
  port: 8080

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          okta:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/custom-login
            user-name-attribute: email

okta:
  oauth2:
    redirect-uri: https://dev-14057786.okta.com/oauth2/default
    client-id: <client ID>
    client-secret: <client-secret>
    issuer: https://dev-14057786.okta.com/oauth2/default
    scopes:
    - openid
    - email
    - profile
```

I am able to get the Okta login page, once i click on login, I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The port must be an integer: 8080https:
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.getPort(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.matchesAuthorizationResponse(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.java:196) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.java:164) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
```

appriciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct the `redirect-uri` in `application.yml` file.

> ```
> okta:
>   oauth2:
>     redirect-uri: https://dev-14057786.okta.com/oauth2/default
> ```

You've mentioned the endpoint of issuer aka auth server which is incorrect. It needs to be client app endpoint. For this specific application you just need to set the `redirect-uri` as following

```
okta:
  oauth2:
    redirect-uri: /authorization-code/callback
```